# How to delete some character from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like `"3 foo, 2 foo, 4 foo"` , which i am getting from a plugin dynamically. But i want to modify it with javascript or jquery to look like `"3, 2, 4 foo"` ! how can i do it?

Comment: Well, we could give you a specific answer to do what you've asked in your question, but you say "a string _like_", implying that it's going to be variable etc - you probably need to provide a lot more information, including what approaches you've taken to tackling the problem, to get a good answer to solve your _real_ problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some regex:

```
"3 foo, 2 foo, 4 foo"
    .split(/ foo,?/g) // matches one space then foo with an optional comma
    .join() // ["3", " 2", " 4", ""] -> "3, 2, 4,"
    .replace(/,$/, " foo") // replace the ending comma with foo
```

Comment: How do i check if a string contain more than one "foo" ?

Comment: `var hasMultipleFoos = "3 foo, 2, 4".split(/ foo,?/g).length > 2;`

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for

Using the function below, you insert the string and the word you want to remove.

```js
var str = "3 foo, 2 foo, 4 foo";

function removeWordFromstring(string, word) {
    var parts = string.split(word);
    if (parts[1]===undefined)
        return string;
    else
        return parts.slice(0,-1).join('') + word + parts.slice(-1)
}

console.log(removeWordFromstring(str, " foo"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I get it wrong,my advice is to use replace() to delete all 'foo',and at last append a 'foo' to the after-deleted string.